Problem with importing some packages in qiskit
I'm a beginner in Quantum computing and I aim to use Qiskit for quantum chemistry calculations (using VQE algorithm). I have a question about importing and would be so grateful for any help.
I have started by reading a book ("Quantum Chemistry and Computing for the Curious") and practicing its exercises, but after executing:
!pip install qiskit
!pip install qiskit-nature
!pip install 'qiskit[visualization]'
!pip install qiskit.utils
!pip install pyscf
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

and when I'm trying to import packages in the initial steps:
from qiskit.visualization import array_to_latex, plot_bloch_vector, plot_bloch_multivector, plot_state_qsphere, plot_state_city
from qiskit import QuantumRegister, ClassicalRegister, QuantumCircuit, transpile
from qiskit import execute, Aer
import qiskit.quantum_info as qi
from qiskit.quantum_info import SparsePauliOp
from qiskit.extensions import Initialize

I get errors for Aer, qiskit.extensions, IBMQ etc:
ImportError: cannot import name 'execute' from 'qiskit' (/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/qiskit/__init__.py)

By googling, I found that Aer is a separated package now and should be installed independently as qiskit-aer. But what about qiskit.extensions for example? How can I find that, what are the updated correct syntaxes for such problems? Qiskit documentation, for example? Please share your Valuable experiences.
Thanks in advance.

Hi, and welcome the the Quantum Computing SE! For your first question, can you tell us which book are you reading? Qiskit underwent many changes in the previous years, and many modules were (re)moved. Also, putting the code you're trying to run would probably be convenient for us to help you. Also, it's better if you can focus to a single question per post. I do think that your second question would be better answered on StackOverflow however, since it seems to me that it's a Python package installing question that isn't fundamentally linked to Qiskit, so don't hesitate to "migrate" it there!

Dear @TristanNemoz Thanks a lot for your comment. I included all information that you mentioned. Also. I asked the second question because I think that it's something about Qiskit packages, not the python packages in general.

I'd just add that execute and extensions have been removed in qiskit 1.0. but initializing a state can be done by another way, I don't think you must install extensions package.

@taketoshikinoshita many thanks, so what is the solution if I want to go ahead with the instruction of the book? Because as I said to you, I'm a beginner and don't know anything about the other methods.

@Wisdom, this is just my personal opinion, but my guess is that there is not going to be an easy solution if you want to follow that book. Based on the code you shared, I can see many of these functions have been deprecated. Chances are you will keep running into code that doesn't work and will have to spend a good amount of time figuring out what's the right syntax to make things work.

@diemilio thanks a lot for your valuable comment and let me know that these functions have been deprecated. So I move to IBMlearning, as it's an up-to-date reference.

Just not import execute and Initialize. The ground-state calc in chapter 5 doesn't use either of them. I could run vqe calc example introduced in the chapter normally with qiskit ver 1.2.4. Just one thing, use the same scipy ver(=1.12.0) as the book's. In my experiment, I got an error when I used the latest scipy ver.. I put my version's info below for your info:
pyqmc                     0.6.0
pyscf                     2.5.0
qiskit                    1.2.4
qiskit-aer                0.15.1
qiskit-algorithms         0.3.0
qiskit-nature             0.7.2
qutip                     5.0.4
scipy                     1.12.0

Here's vqe result :
Fermionic Hamiltonian operator
Fermionic Operator
number spin orbitals=4, number terms=36
  -1.25633907300325 * ( +_0 -_0 )
+ -0.47189600728114184 * ( +_1 -_1 )
+ -1.25633907300325 * ( +_2 -_2 )
+ -0.47189600728114184 * ( +_3 -_3 )
+ 0.3378550774017583 * ( +_0 +_0 -_0 -_0 )
+ 0.3322908651276482 * ( +_0 +_1 -_1 -_0 )
+ 0.3378550774017583 * ( +_0 +_2 -_2 -_0 )
+ 0.3322908651276482 * ( +_0 +_3 -_3 -_0 )
+ 0.09046559989211572 * ( +_0 +_0 -_1 -_1 )
+ 0.09046559989211572 * ( +_0 +_1 -_0 -_1 )
+ 0.09046559989211572 * ( +_0 +_2 -_3 -_1 )
+ 0.09046559989211572 * ( +_0 +_3 -_2 -_1 )
+ 0.09046559989211572 * ( +_1 +_0 -_1 -_0 )
+ 0.09046559989211572 * ( +_1 +_1 -_0 -_0 )
+ 0.09046559989211572 * ( +_1 +_2 -_3 -_0 )
+ 0.09046559989211572 * ( +_1 +_3 -_2 -_0 )
+ 0.3322908651276482 * ( +_1 +_0 -_0 -_1 )
+ 0.34928686136600906 * ( +_1 +_1 -_1 -_1 )
...
Number of particles: (1, 1)
Number of spin orbitals: 4
 
Qubit Hamiltonian operator
Parity transformation 
Number of items in the Pauli list: 5
SparsePauliOp(['II', 'IZ', 'ZI', 'ZZ', 'XX'],
              coeffs=[-1.05237325+0.j,  0.39793742+0.j, -0.39793742+0.j, -0.0112801 +0.j,
  0.1809312 +0.j])
 
PySCF restricted HF (RHF) converged ground-state energy: -1.116998996754
Iteration, Energy, Error
0:         -1.1228 0.0062
1:         -1.1442 0.0065
2:         -1.1505 0.0094
3:         -1.1645 0.0098
PyQMC Monte Carlo converged ground-state energy: -1.164471574833, error: 0.0098
QPE computed electronic ground state energy (Hartree): -1.2993947842045661
 
Running the VQE using the NumPy exact solver
Elapsed time: 0:00:00.066147 

=== GROUND STATE ENERGY ===
 
* Electronic ground state energy (Hartree): -1.857275030202
  - computed part:      -1.857275030202
~ Nuclear repulsion energy (Hartree): 0.719968994449
> Total ground state energy (Hartree): -1.137306035753
 
=== MEASURED OBSERVABLES ===
 
  0:  # Particles: 2.000 S: 0.000 S^2: 0.000 M: 0.000
 
=== DIPOLE MOMENTS ===
 
~ Nuclear dipole moment (a.u.): [0.0  0.0  1.3889487]
 
  0: 
  * Electronic dipole moment (a.u.): [0.0  0.0  1.388948701555]
    - computed part:      [0.0  0.0  1.388948701555]
  > Dipole moment (a.u.): [0.0  0.0  -0.000000001555]  Total: 0.000000001555
                 (debye): [0.0  0.0  -0.000000003953]  Total: 0.000000003953

Edit :
The reference code is Chapter_05_Variational_Quantum_Eigensolver_(VQE)_algorithm_V3.ipynb. I've only edited those importing part, the rest is the same as that reference.
Here's a bunch of package installations in google colab
!pip install pyqmc

!pip install qiskit

!pip install qiskit-aer

!pip install qiskit-algorithms

!pip install qiskit-nature

!pip install qutip

!pip install ase

!pip install qutip

!pip install scipy

!nvcc --version
#nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
#Copyright (c) 2005-2023 NVIDIA Corporation
#Built on Tue_Aug_15_22:02:13_PDT_2023
#Cuda compilation tools, release 12.2, V12.2.140
#Build cuda_12.2.r12.2/compiler.33191640_0
 
!pip install cupy-cuda12x -U 
#I installed cuda12x because my cuda compiler version was 12.2

Here's a code. If you encounter an error something like,
"CUDARuntimeError: cudaErrorInsufficientDriver: CUDA driver version is insufficient for CUDA runtime version" first time, I suggest you run the code a few times. (When I saw the error the code ran fine by just running it again.)
from qiskit.visualization import array_to_latex, plot_bloch_vector, plot_bloch_multivector, plot_state_qsphere, plot_state_city
from qiskit import QuantumRegister, ClassicalRegister, QuantumCircuit, transpile
from qiskit_aer import AerSimulator, Aer

from qiskit_nature.second_q.formats.molecule_info import MoleculeInfo
from qiskit_nature.units import DistanceUnit
from qiskit_nature.second_q.mappers import ParityMapper, JordanWignerMapper, BravyiKitaevMapper
from qiskit_nature.second_q.properties import ParticleNumber
from qiskit_nature.second_q.transformers import ActiveSpaceTransformer, FreezeCoreTransformer
from qiskit_nature import settings
from qiskit.primitives import Sampler, StatevectorSampler
from qiskit_algorithms import HamiltonianPhaseEstimation, PhaseEstimation
from qiskit.primitives import Estimator
from qiskit_algorithms.optimizers import SLSQP, SPSA, QNSPSA
from qiskit_nature.second_q.circuit.library import UCCSD, HartreeFock
from qiskit_algorithms.minimum_eigensolvers import NumPyMinimumEigensolver, VQE
from qiskit_nature.second_q.algorithms.ground_state_solvers import GroundStateEigensolver
from qiskit.circuit.library import TwoLocal
from functools import partial as apply_variation
from qiskit.circuit.library import Initialize
from qiskit.quantum_info import SparsePauliOp
from qiskit_nature.second_q.mappers import ParityMapper, JordanWignerMapper, BravyiKitaevMapper
from qiskit_nature.second_q.properties import ParticleNumber
from qiskit_nature.second_q.transformers import ActiveSpaceTransformer, FreezeCoreTransformer
from qiskit_nature.second_q.operators import FermionicOp
from qiskit_nature.second_q.operators import ElectronicIntegrals
from pyscf import gto, scf
from ase import Atoms
from ase.build import molecule
from ase.visualize import view
from qiskit_nature.second_q.drivers import PySCFDriver

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import qiskit.quantum_info as qi
import os.path
#import pyqmc.api as pyq
import pyqmc.api as pyq
import h5py
import cmath
import math
import scipy.stats as stats
import qutip
import time, datetime
import pandas as pd

def p(x):
  if x < 0:
    y = 0
  else:
    y = np.exp(-x)
  return(y)
n = 10000 # Size of the Markov chain stationary distribution

# Use np.linspace to create an array of n numbers between 0 and n
index = np.linspace(0, n, num=n)
x = np.linspace(0, n, num=n)

x[0] = 3     # Initialize to 3
for i in range(1, n):
  current_x = x[i-1]

  # We add a N(0,1) random number to x
  proposed_x = current_x + stats.norm.rvs(loc=0, scale=1, size=1, random_state=None)

  A = min(1, p(proposed_x)/p(current_x))

  r = np.random.uniform(0,1) # Generate a uniform random number in [0, 1]

  if r < A:
    x[i] = proposed_x       # Accept move with probabilty min(1,A)
  else:
    x[i] = current_x        # Otherwise "reject" move, and stay where we are

plt.plot(index, x, label="Trace plot")
plt.xlabel('Index')
plt.ylabel('MH value')
plt.legend()
plt.show()

q25, q75 = np.percentile(x, [25, 75])
bin_width = 2 * (q75 - q25) * len(x) ** (-1/3)
bins = round((x.max() - x.min()) / bin_width)
print("Freedman–Diaconis number of bins:", bins)
#Freedman–Diaconis number of bins: 72
plt.hist(x, density=True, bins=bins)
plt.ylabel('Density')
plt.xlabel('x');

def run_PySCF(info_dict, pyqmc=True, show=True):
  # Reset the files
  for fname in ['mf.hdf5','optimized_wf.hdf5','vmc_data.hdf5','dmc.hdf5']:
    if os.path.isfile(fname):
        os.remove(fname)
  
  atoms = info_dict['atoms']
  coords = info_dict['coords']
  charge = info_dict['charge']
  multiplicity = info_dict['multiplicity']
  atom_pair = info_dict['atom_pair']

  s = ''
  k = 0
  for atom in atoms:
    s += atoms[k] + ' ' + str(coords[k][0]) + ' ' + str(coords[k][1]) + ' ' + str(coords[k][2]) + '; '
    k += 1
  s = s[0:-2]
  
  mol_PySCF = gto.M(atom = s)
  
  mf = scf.RHF(mol_PySCF)
  mf.chkfile = "mf.hdf5"
  
  conv, e, mo_e, mo, mo_occ = scf.hf.kernel(mf)
  if show:
    if conv:
      print("PySCF restricted HF (RHF) converged ground-state energy: {:.12f}".format(e))
    else:
      print("PySCF restricted HF (RHF) ground-state computation failed to converge")

  if pyqmc:
    pyq.OPTIMIZE("mf.hdf5",# Construct a Slater-Jastrow wave function from the pyscf output
      "optimized_wf.hdf5", # Store optimized parameters in this file.
      nconfig=100,         # Optimize using this many Monte Carlo samples/configurations
      max_iterations=4,    # 4 optimization steps
      verbose=False)

    with h5py.File("optimized_wf.hdf5") as f:
      iter = f['iteration']
      energy = f['energy']
      error = f['energy_error']
      l = energy.shape[0]
      e = energy[l-1]
      err = error[l-1]
      if show:
        if err < 0.1:
          print("Iteration, Energy, Error")
          for k in iter:
            print("{}:         {:.4f} {:.4f}".format(k, energy[k], error[k]))
          print("PyQMC Monte Carlo converged ground-state energy: {:.12f}, error: {:.4f}".format(e, err))
        else:
          print("PyQMC Monte Carlo failed to converge")

  return conv, e

def U(theta):
  unitary = QuantumCircuit(1)
  unitary.p(np.pi*2*theta, 0)
  return unitary
def do_qpe(unitary, nqubits=3, show=True):
  state_in = QuantumCircuit(1)
  state_in.x(0)
  pe = PhaseEstimation(num_evaluation_qubits=nqubits, sampler = Sampler())
  result = pe.estimate(unitary, state_in)
  phase_out = result.phase
  if show:
    print("Number of qubits: {}, QPE phase estimate: {}".format(nqubits, phase_out))
  return(phase_out)
theta = 1/2 + 1/4 + 1/8
print("theta: {}".format(theta))
unitary = U(theta)
result = do_qpe(unitary, nqubits=3)

def U(theta):
  unitary = QuantumCircuit(1)
  unitary.p(np.pi*2*theta, 0)
  return unitary
def do_qpe(unitary, nqubits=3, show=True):
  state_in = QuantumCircuit(1)
  state_in.x(0)
  pe = PhaseEstimation(num_evaluation_qubits=nqubits, sampler = Sampler())
  result = pe.estimate(unitary, state_in)
  phase_out = result.phase
  if show:
    print("Number of qubits: {}, QPE phase estimate: {}".format(nqubits, phase_out))
  return(phase_out)
theta = 1/2 + 1/4 + 1/8
print("theta: {}".format(theta))
unitary = U(theta)
result = do_qpe(unitary, nqubits=3)

numpy_solver = NumPyMinimumEigensolver()
tl_circuit = TwoLocal(rotation_blocks = ['h', 'rx'], entanglement_blocks = 'cz',
                      entanglement='full', reps=2, parameter_prefix = 'y')
# Leveraging Qiskit Runtime
# https://qiskit.org/documentation/nature/tutorials/07_leveraging_qiskit_runtime.html

#vqe_tl_solver = VQE(ansatz = tl_circuit,
                     #quantum_instance = QuantumInstance(Aer.get_backend('aer_simulator_statevector')))
estimator = Estimator()
optimizer = SPSA(maxiter=100)
vqe_tl_solver = VQE(estimator, tl_circuit, optimizer)
#vqe_ucc_solver = VQEUCCFactory(quantum_instance, ansatz = tl_circuit)
#https://qiskit.org/documentation/nature/tutorials/03_ground_state_solvers.html
#vqe_ucc_solver = VQEUCCFactory(Estimator(), UCCSD(), SLSQP())
#vqe_ucc_solver is now defined in solve_ground_state()
qnspsa_loss = []
def qnspsa_callback(nfev, x, fx, stepsize, accepted):
    qnspsa_loss.append(fx)
# Sampling the potential energy surface
_EPS = 1e-2 # Global variable used to chop small numbers to zero
def bopes(info_dict, mapper_name, num_electrons, num_spatial_orbitals, two_qubit_reduction, z2symmetry_reduction,
          name_solver, perturbation_steps, mapper, solver, show=True):
  
  atoms = info_dict['atoms']
  coords = info_dict['coords']
  charge = info_dict['charge']
  multiplicity = info_dict['multiplicity']
  atom_pair = info_dict['atom_pair']

  size = len(perturbation_steps)
  
  energy = np.empty(size)

  x0 = coords[atom_pair[0]][0]
  y0 = coords[atom_pair[0]][1]
  z0 = coords[atom_pair[0]][2]
  if show:
    print("x0, y0, z0 :", x0, y0, z0)
  
  x1 = coords[atom_pair[1]][0]
  y1 = coords[atom_pair[1]][1]
  z1 = coords[atom_pair[1]][2]
  if show:
    print("x1, y1, z1 :", x1, y1, z1)
    
  if abs(x1 - x0) > _EPS:
    # Find the equation of a straight line y = m*x + p that crosses the points of the atom pair
    m = (y1 - y0)/(x1 - x0)
    p = y0 - m*x0  
  
  for k in range(size):
    if (abs(x0)<_EPS and abs(y0)<_EPS):
      z0_new = z0 + perturbation_steps[k]
      coords_new = []
      for l in range(len(coords)):
        if l == atom_pair[0]:
          coords_new.append((0.0, 0.0, z0_new))
        else:
          coords_new.append(coords[l])

    elif (abs(z0)<_EPS and abs(z1)<_EPS):
      x0_new = x0 + perturbation_steps[k]
      y0_new = m*x0_new + p
      coords_new = []
      for l in range(len(coords)):
        if l == atom_pair[0]:
          coords_new.append((x0_new, y0_new, 0.0))
        else:
          coords_new.append(coords[l])
    
    info_dict_new={'atoms':atoms, 'coords':coords_new, 'charge':charge, 
                  'multiplicity':multiplicity, 'atom_pair':atom_pair}
    
    fermionic_hamiltonian, num_particles, num_spin_orbitals, qubit_op, mapper, ground_state = \
    solve_ground_state(info_dict_new, mapper_name=mapper_name, num_electrons=num_electrons, num_spatial_orbitals=num_spatial_orbitals,
                  two_qubit_reduction=two_qubit_reduction, z2symmetry_reduction=z2symmetry_reduction, 
                  name_solver=name_solver, solver=solver, pyqmc=False)
    
    energy[k] = ground_state.total_energies
    
  return perturbation_steps, energy

def get_particle_number(problem, show=True):
  
  # https://qiskit.org/documentation/nature/stubs/qiskit_nature.second_q.problems.ElectronicStructureProblem.num_spin_orbitals.html
  num_spin_orbitals = problem.num_spin_orbitals
  num_particles = problem.num_particles
  
  if show:
    print("Number of particles: {}".format(num_particles))
    print("Number of spin orbitals: {}".format(num_spin_orbitals))
    
  return num_particles, num_spin_orbitals
def fermion_to_qubit(problem, second_q_op, mapper_name, truncate=20, two_qubit_reduction=False, z2symmetry_reduction=None, show=True): 
# Electronic Structure Problems with v0.5
# https://qiskit.org/documentation/nature/migration/00b_Electronic_structure_with_v0.5.html
# https://qiskit.org/documentation/nature/stubs/qiskit_nature.second_q.mappers.QubitConverter.html#qubitconverter
# https://qiskit.org/ecosystem/nature/migration/0.6_c_qubit_converter.html
  if show:
    print("Qubit Hamiltonian operator")
    print("{} transformation ". format(mapper_name))

  match mapper_name:
    case "Jordan-Wigner":
      mapper = JordanWignerMapper()
    case "Parity":
      mapper = ParityMapper(num_particles=problem.num_particles)
    case "Bravyi-Kitaev":
      mapper = BravyiKitaevMapper()
  
  qubit_op = mapper.map(second_q_op)
  
  if z2symmetry_reduction != None:
    tapered_mapper = problem.get_tapered_mapper(mapper)
    qubit_op = tapered_mapper.map(second_q_op)
    
  n_items = len(qubit_op)
  if show:
    print("Number of items in the Pauli list:", n_items)
    if n_items <= truncate:
      print(qubit_op)
    else:
      print(qubit_op[0:truncate])
  return qubit_op, mapper
# Leveraging Qiskit Runtime
# https://qiskit.org/documentation/nature/tutorials/07_leveraging_qiskit_runtime.html
def run_vqe(name, problem, qubit_converter, solver, show=True):
  calc = GroundStateEigensolver(qubit_converter, solver)
  start = time.time()
  ground_state = calc.solve(problem)
  elapsed = str(datetime.timedelta(seconds = time.time()-start))
  if show:
    print("Running the VQE using the {}".format(name))
    print("Elapsed time: {} \n".format(elapsed))
    print(ground_state)
  return ground_state
def run_qpe(qubit_op, n_ancillae=3, num_time_slices=1, show=True):
  
  qpe = HamiltonianPhaseEstimation(n_ancillae, sampler=Sampler())#StatevectorSampler())
  state_preparation = None
  result = qpe.estimate(qubit_op, state_preparation, evolution=None)

  if show:
    eigv = np.real(result.most_likely_eigenvalue)
    print("QPE computed electronic ground state energy (Hartree): {}".format(eigv))
  
  return eigv
def plot_energy_landscape(dist, energy):
  if len(dist) > 1:
      plt.plot(dist, energy, label="VQE Energy")
      plt.xlabel('Atomic distance Deviation(Angstrom)')
      plt.ylabel('Energy (hartree)')
      plt.legend()
      plt.show()
  else:
      print("Total Energy is: ", energy_surface_result.energies[0], "hartree")
      print("(No need to plot, only one configuration calculated.)")
  return
def plot_loss(loss, label, target):
  plt.figure(figsize=(12, 6))
  plt.plot(loss, 'tab:green', ls='--', label=label)
  plt.axhline(target, c='tab:red', ls='--', label='target')
  plt.ylabel('loss')
  plt.xlabel('iterations')
  plt.legend()
settings.use_pauli_sum_op = False

def solve_ground_state(
    info_dict,
    mapper_name="Parity",
    num_electrons=None,
    num_spatial_orbitals=None,
    freeze_core=None, 
    two_qubit_reduction=False,
    z2symmetry_reduction = "Auto",
    name_solver='NumPy exact solver',
    solver=NumPyMinimumEigensolver(),
    plot_bopes=False,
    perturbation_steps=np.linspace(-1, 1, 3),
    pyqmc=True,
    n_ancillae=3, 
    num_time_slices=1,
    loss=[],
    label=None,
    target=None,
    show=True
):
    
    atoms = info_dict['atoms']
    coords = info_dict['coords']
    charge = info_dict['charge']
    multiplicity = info_dict['multiplicity']
    atom_pair = info_dict['atom_pair']
    
    moleculeinfo = MoleculeInfo(atoms, coords, charge=charge, multiplicity=multiplicity)
    
    # Defining the electronic structure molecule driver
    # Electronic Structure Problems with v0.5
    # https://qiskit.org/documentation/nature/migration/00b_Electronic_structure_with_v0.5.html
    # https://qiskit.org/documentation/nature/tutorials/01_electronic_structure.html
    
    #driver = ElectronicStructureMoleculeDriver(molecule, basis='sto3g', driver_type=ElectronicStructureDriverType.PYSCF)
    driver = PySCFDriver.from_molecule(moleculeinfo, basis="sto3g")

    # Splitting into classical and quantum
    if num_electrons != None and num_spatial_orbitals != None:
      # https://qiskit.org/documentation/nature/tutorials/05_problem_transformers.html
      # https://qiskit.org/documentation/nature/stubs/qiskit_nature.second_q.transformers.ActiveSpaceTransformer.html#activespacetransformer
      split = ActiveSpaceTransformer(num_electrons=num_electrons, num_spatial_orbitals=num_spatial_orbitals)
    else:
      split = None

    # Define an electronic structure problem
    problem = driver.run()
    if split != None:
      problem = split.transform(problem)
    elif freeze_core != None:
      problem = freeze_core.transform(problem)
    
    # Get the electronic energy fermionic Hamiltonian
    fermionic_hamiltonian = problem.hamiltonian
    second_q_op = fermionic_hamiltonian.second_q_op()
    
    if show:
      print("Fermionic Hamiltonian operator")
      # We print the first 20 terms of the fermionic Hamiltonian operator of the molecule
      # https://qiskit.org/documentation/nature/migration/00b_Electronic_structure_with_v0.5.html
      print("\n".join(str(second_q_op).splitlines()[:20] + ["..."]))
    
     # Get number of particles and number of spin orbitals
    num_particles, num_spin_orbitals = get_particle_number(problem, show=show)
    
    # Use the function fermion_to_qubit() to convert a fermionic operator to a qubit operator
    if show:
      print(" ")
    qubit_op, mapper = fermion_to_qubit(problem, second_q_op, mapper_name, two_qubit_reduction=two_qubit_reduction, z2symmetry_reduction=z2symmetry_reduction, show=show)
    
    # Run the the PySCF RHF method
    if show:
      print(" ")
    conv, e = run_PySCF(info_dict, pyqmc=pyqmc, show=show)
    #conv, e = run_PySCF(info_dict, pyqmc=False, show=show)
    
    # Run QPE
    eigv = run_qpe(qubit_op, n_ancillae=n_ancillae, num_time_slices=num_time_slices, show=show)

    # Run VQE
    if show:
      print(" ")
    
    #https://qiskit.org/ecosystem/nature/howtos/vqe_ucc.html
    if name_solver == 'UCCSD ansatz':
      ansatz = UCCSD(
        problem.num_spatial_orbitals,
        problem.num_particles,
        mapper,
        initial_state=HartreeFock(problem.num_spatial_orbitals,problem.num_particles,mapper),
        )
      solver = VQE(Estimator(), ansatz, SLSQP())
    
    ground_state = run_vqe(name_solver, problem, mapper, solver, show=show)
    # Plot loss function
    if loss != []:
      plot_loss(loss, label, target)
    
    if plot_bopes:
      # Compute the potential energy surface
      dist, energy = bopes(info_dict, mapper_name, num_electrons, num_spatial_orbitals, two_qubit_reduction, z2symmetry_reduction,
          name_solver, perturbation_steps, mapper, solver, show=True)
      
      # Plot the energy as a function of atomic separation
      plot_energy_landscape(dist, energy)

    return fermionic_hamiltonian, num_particles, num_spin_orbitals, qubit_op, mapper, ground_state

# Electronic Structure Problems with v0.5
# https://qiskit.org/documentation/nature/migration/00b_Electronic_structure_with_v0.5.html
H2_atoms = ["H", "H"]
H2_coords = [(0.0, 0.0, 0.0), (0.0, 0.0, 0.735)]
H2_charge = 0
H2_multiplicity = 1
H2_atom_pair=(1, 0)
H2_info_dict={'atoms':H2_atoms, 'coords':H2_coords, 'charge':H2_charge, 'multiplicity':H2_multiplicity, 'atom_pair':H2_atom_pair}

H2_moleculeinfo = MoleculeInfo(H2_atoms, H2_coords, charge=H2_charge, multiplicity=H2_multiplicity)

H2_fermionic_hamiltonian, H2_num_particles, H2_num_spin_orbitals, H2_qubit_op, H2_qubit_converter, H2_ground_state = \
                  solve_ground_state(H2_info_dict, mapper_name="Parity",
                  two_qubit_reduction=True, z2symmetry_reduction=None, 
                  name_solver = 'NumPy exact solver', solver = numpy_solver)


oh, thanks a lot for your answer. It's a big deal to me. But one more thing: regarding the possible errors, and that I'm a newbie, can you please include the whole code led to this result, in your answer? Thanks.

I've added the code, please take a look.

thanks a lot. However, when I run the code I get Failed to import CuPy. and when I try to install it using pip install cupy returns error, so I tried !pip install -U cupy-cuda11x and it was successfully, but unfortunately your code returns an error for cupy again: ImportError: cannot import name 'core' from partially initialized module 'cupy._core' (most likely due to a circular import) (/content/cupy/cupy/_core/__init__.py) any idea?

Ah, I see you're using a GPU in google colab. I've updated  the code, could you try it again?

OMG! It finally worked! Thank you very much. Can you please give me some hints about the problem for some possible future errors? And do you think it's a good idea to go ahead with the book regarding such incompatibilities? I can't find the right versions of packages despite you!

Here's qiskit releases page, you may find some info about (future) incompatibilities in changelog. Why not? the book you introduced looks very interesting :)
